# Походження вислову "робити гроші з повітря"

Tags: фразеологізми, сталий-вираз

Не раз чув вислів "робити гроші з повітря", який означає: "Легко заробляти гроші". Однак, нещодавно задумався про його походження.

В Інтернеті я не знайшов жодної інформації, виразу "робити гроші з повітря" не було серед [крилатих висловів і їх значень](https://podskazok.net/ua/pryslivia-prykazky-aforyzmy/krylati-vyslovy-i-ikh-znachennia.html). Однак, знаю, що він вживається ([приклад 1](http://h.ua/story/69454/) і [приклад 2](https://uacredity.com/yak-robiti-groshi-z-povitrya-abo-zarobitok-na-poserednictvi/)).

Особисто у мене є теорія, що сам вислів пов'язаний із фокусами, де фокусник дістає гроші з повітря. Проте, у мене немає ніяких доказів, щоб це підтвердити.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Походження цього виразу - англійське: to make money out of thin air ([приклад](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HN9Y67O)).

Не думаю, що "робити гроші з повітря" звучить дуже автентично (тому ми і не знаходимо його у словнику), проте, як ми бачимо, вираз використовується, особливо молоддю.

[image]

Ви маєте рацію щодо асоціації з фокусником. Англійське "out of thin air" означає "несподівано", "нізвідки". Тож якщо щось з'являється "out of thin air", або "з повітря", воно з'являється неначе кролик із капелюха фокусника (таке тлумачення англійського виразу можно прочитати [тут](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/out%20of%20thin%20air)).